# Integer part of positive integral multiples of the cube root of 3.

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Assume that $m\geq{2}$ is an integer. I am trying to prove the following inequality. If $[x]$ denotes the integer part of the real number $x$, then $$[{{\sqrt[3]{3}}m}]^3 - [{{\sqrt[3]{3}}m}]< 3m^3 - 3m.$$ Is there an obvious reason why this would not hold? Numerical calculations (approximating the cube root of 3 by ${\sqrt[3]{3}} = 1.4422$) show that the inequality holds, and that the difference is actually increasing for $2\leq{m}\leq{17}.$ So I have faith that the inequality may be true!
I was trying to use mathematical induction on $m$, but am having a hard time formulating the argument. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did this question come from? Context would be useful!

Comment: If I can prove this inequality, I can show that a cubic Diophantine equation has no positive integral solutions! But the argument would to take too much space to write down!

Comment: Can you explain how you got the upper bound in the above displayed inequality?